# tableview finds nil while using a xib cell

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

i'm trying to use a xib file as cell in a table view. but it says "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" on registerNib. i think it's about referencing outlet but i don't know why it occurs.
my view is as follow:

[image]

as it shows, table view is inside Play Video View Controller.

my viewDidLoad is:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "NewestTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "NewestTableViewCell")
}
```

and table view methods:

```
// MARK: - Table view data source
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return video.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell : NewestTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("NewestTableViewCell") as! NewestTableViewCell

    let vd = video[indexPath.row]

    cell.title.text = vd.title
    cell.title.textAlignment = .Right
    cell.duration.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    cell.duration.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    cell.duration.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0
    cell.duration.clipsToBounds = true
    cell.duration.text = vd.length
    imageDl(vd.imageUrl){ image in
        cell.videoImage.image = image
    }
    cell.time.text = vd.published
    cell.time.textAlignment = .Right
    cell.viewed.text = vd.view
    cell.viewed.textAlignment = .Right


    return cell
}
```

I used this nib in other TableViewControllers but when using in UIViewController which contains tableView, it'n not working. what reason causes this?

thanks

Comment: Has the xib been instantiated?

Comment: @penatheboss i just have registerNib in viewDidLoad. where should i instantiate it and how?

Comment: The Xcode screen image is showing that the UITableView is connected to the `view` property of your ViewController, not to the property `tableView`.

Comment: @OOPer thanks! i' new on iOS and still need some understanding about concepts

Answer (score 1):

The only thing in the line that could be forcefully unwrapped is your tableView. Check its referencing outlet.